# Format string for gauges in ComponentArt

Tags: c#, wpf, componentart

Is there a way to put some format in the value of a gauge? this is my code (XAML)

```
    <ComponentArt:NumericGauge Height="80" 
        Name="Gauge1" 
        Width="300" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
        Margin="0,8,0,8" 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Value="900000" 
     />
```

I want my gauge value like this: $ 900.000

My program is developed in c#

Thanks in advance

EDIT: More information=I'm developing an wpf application with c# in visual studio, I'm using ComponentArt to develop a "Gauge" this is some sample code from the componentart webpage

http://dv2011.componentart.com/#/Views/DemoViewPage.xaml$control=Gauges&category=Numeric_Gauges&demo=Numeric_Gauge

Comment: where is this code currently is this in a .config file..? can you show more code or explain a little more in detail

Comment: Either retemplate the control or maybe you can do something similar to what this guy did.
http://www.componentart.com/community/forums/t/63716.aspx

Comment: @colinsmith I tried that sample before, with FormatString="0.#0%" I get 900000,00%

Answer (score 0):

At http://www.componentart.com/community/forums/t/63716.aspx there's someone using the NumericGauge - they've provided some example code Numeric_5F00_Gauge.zip.

Inside, they are using FormatString to provide the % symbol. I guess you could try doing FormatString="$ 0.#0" or something similar? (maybe more 0's for more significant decimal places), and change your Value to 900.

Comment: yes, I found the proper format, my solution is in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, this is the FormatString to get $ 90.000

```
FormatString="$ #,#0"
```